# Scihub Database Information

Tags: mysql, azure-search-.net-sdk

This is the **information post** as I searched a lot to see the db schema before downloading the SQL databasefrom Sci-Hub mentioned [here](https://sci-hub.se/database). Hence providing the relevant information if anyone further requires it.

[image]

Total records in the database is greater than 55000000. The db includes of PubmedID as well.

---

Comment: There is no question ? Voting to close as not about programming so off topic.

Comment: If you want to provide some information, then you should ASL a question, like "What is Scihub  db schema?" and then post the answer. Though I still doubt such a question is on topic